# Automatic deletion of a question

Tags: support, questions, auto-delete

Is there any automatic deletion of a question in place?  I saw the [I did it for the lulz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098861/i-did-it-for-the-lulz-c-php) question and figured this would get deleted right away, but it didn't.  Seems like after about -10 its probably safe to auto-delete it if a moderator hasn't.

Comment: Mods aside, 20k users can vote to delete any closed post at any time. Takes three votes to make it happen.

Comment: @Popular - Thanks, yeah I just noticed that finally happened.

Comment: The only automatic deletion is for posts flagged as spam (or offensive?). When they hit 6 votes they get deleted.

Comment: Well, there's also the [auto-deletion of old, unanswered questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).

Comment: @Al Everett - I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- As Al pointed out in comments, there are [automatic deletion processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) in place for old, unanswered questions.
- Users with 20k+ rep [have the ability](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) to vote to delete any post (question or answer) with a score of -1 or lower, and immediately vote to delete any closed question.
- Questions are subject to content quality filtering and blocking. Even if a question manages to get through the filters and is still bad enough to be downvoted that much, I would say it's a pretty rare case, and the community can effectively deal with that through the other means I mentioned.

I don't have 10k to look at the specific question you're talking about, but if there's a -10 post on SO, there's a very good chance of it being removed quickly without any system-automated intervention. At this time, I don't see a need for any new system to handle these edge cases.

Comment: Good points.  I think that last point handles my question.  I was thinking at some downvote threshold the question could be auto-deleted. The question was at -19 when finally deleted (overall was +2/-21).  Thanks for answering.